# Is there a way with to prevent "git stash pop" from marking files as modified?

Tags: git, git-stash

I implemented a git-hook to scan my commits through pyflakes and jshint, and after reading Yipit's commentary on [why most pre-commit hooks are broken](http://tech.yipit.com/2011/11/16/183772396/), I chose to implement his `git stash` and `git stash pop` suggestions.

Unfortunately, `git stash pop` marks the files as 'modified', which then causes my IDE to warn me whenever I go back to that page " modified on disk.  Reread from disk?"  It then asks "Are you sure you want to edit this buffer?" and finally "Are you sure you want to save this buffer over a modified file?"

I appreciate everything it's trying to do for me, but it's asking me about functionally non-existent "changes".

Short of playing weird guessing games with `touch` is there some way to prevent `git stash pop` from marking all of the files it touched as changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so (timestamp is altered, as mentioned in "[GIT: Adding Local Changes to Non-Current Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625061/6309)" for instance).

The easiest way would be configure your IDE to refresh automatically.

For Eclipse for instance, this would be the setting ["Refresh on Access"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049245/6309).

---

Another approach would be to keep another *local* repo (one where there is no local modification ever, so no need to stash).
Your pre-commit hook remains in your current repo.

Your hook would use your current index (what you have added), but the *other* work-tree repo.
For that, you would need to commit with:

```
git commit --work-tree=/path/to/other/local/repo -m "my commit message"
```

If the hook doesn't fail, you can have a post-commit hook (still in your current repo) go to the other repo, and pull the current branch, updating its (pristine) working tree.

```
cd /path/to/other/local/repo 
git --work-tree=/path/to/other/local/repo --git-dir=/path/to/other/local/repo/.git pull
```

(Note how your hook, which lives in your first repo, needs to specify `work-tree` and `git-dir` of the second repo, in order to work properly).
That is a simplified proposal as it doesn't take into account the current branch you are working on (it assumes only one branch 'master').
But you can [detect the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332273/6309) and adapt from there the hook (with the proper checkout and switch to the right branch).

After the second repo update of its working tree (by the post-commit hook of the first repo), that second repo is ready to serve as a pristine working tree against which your pre-commit hook (of your first and current repo) can safely operate.

Comment: Note to self: And that was my **7000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 52 months), 6 months after the [6000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11644343/6309). Before that [5000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917396/6309), [4000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4953561/6309),  [3000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3074849/6309),  [2000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2027976/6309),  and [1000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/665252/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the changes are non-existant? If the file is showing as modified, something has changed, even if it's whitespace or the permission (executable state) of a file.
You can use `git diff` to see the changes. You can also review the changes by using the `git commit -av` command (the -v flag will display the diff of the commit).

Your IDE is going to keep a current "buffer" state of a file. If that file changes on the disk (which `git stash pop|apply` will do), the IDE will recognize this and unless you have it set to automatically refresh the file (usually in your IDE settings/preferences), it may prompt you if you want to save the current buffer as a new file -- which is not typically necessary when using git -- or to re-load the buffer with the changed state of the file.